# Excel formula: Find Date from Weeknum and weekday

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the date out of a weeknum, weekday and year.

There are many information on the web but after several attempts, I couldn't find what I was looking for.

So far, I have this formula:

```
=DATE(AZ22,1,AZ3*7-5)-WEEKDAY(DATE(AZ22,1,3))
```

- AZ22=YEAR
- AZ3=WEEKNUM

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.
In order to add some complexity, my weeks should start for Thursday (Thursday 1st day of the week).

If you are so kind to provide an answer, could you please post the explanation of the formula as well?

as JvdV asked, the output should be a date like
01 dec 2019.
I need this formula to map a current date (and I can't use date-364) with the last two years.

The process works as follow:

- I have the current date (date A)
- The current week ( of date A) is mapped with a different week last year
- From the week (and eventually the WEEKDAY) I should find my date B

  I hope it clarifies my request

Thank you,

Comment: So can you give an example of input data and expected output/desired result?

Comment: If you are using `WEEKDAY()` to start counting on a thursday you have forgotten to include the return type `14` at least.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=DATE(A2,1,(B2-1)*7-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,B2*7),14)+C2)
```

This is just math.  But by adding the `14` to the Weekday we start our week on Thursday.  This does assume that `2019-1-3`, the first Thursday of this year, is the start of the 2nd week.  If that is not the case and the week that started on the 3rd is the first week, change the `(B2-1)` to just `B2`

[image]

Comment: hello Scott, thank you for the reply, I checked your formula and I got a different result than the one expected: for example: Year 2018, weeknum 2, weekday 1: I am getting 1/11/2018 while it should be 1/8/2018. Am I missing something?

Comment: then you are giving us bad info.  The 2nd Thursday (WeekNum 2 and Weekday 1) is 1/11/2018. You stated your weeks start on Thursday.  So that is correct.   So either you week starts on Monday or you are looking at the calendar wrong.